# Kernel module makefile output name

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-kernel

I am trying to compile my kernel module.
The .c file name is `file1.c`, but I need the .ko file name to be `mod1.ko`.

How can I do that?

My current makefile:

```
obj-m := mod1.o
KDIR :=/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PDW := $(shell pwd)

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PDW) modules

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PDW) clean
```

Comment: Did you tried to rename file1.c into mod1.c ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution looks like this:

```
obj-m += mod1.o
mod1-objs := file1.o

KBUILD_CPPFLAGS += -I$(PWD)/

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: I think you should change `fw-objs` to `mod1-objs` for this to actually work.

Answer (score 8):

You should change your first line to something like this:

```
obj-m += module_name.o
module_name-y := file1.o
```

Where `module_name` is the module file name (in this example the output will be `module_name.ko`) and it will be build from `file1.c`. You can add more than one source file to the 2nd line, so it could be:

```
module_name-y := file1.o file2.o file3.o
```

In this case `module_name.ko` will be build from `file1.c`, `file2.c` and `file3.c`.

You should read [this document](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt) if you want to fully understand Linux kernel makefiles. Your problem is described somewhere around line 190.